# Python 3x- Compression Makes File Bigger :(

Tags: python, compression

Ok. Recently I was testing out a piece of code for a small project. It required me to compress some files, and it actually makes the file size bigger, unless there is a problem in what it prints. Here's my code:

```
def Compress(z):
    #Line Spacing May Be Off A Little Because I'm New to Stack Overflow
    import zlib, sys, time, base64
    text = open(z, "rb").read()
    print ("Raw Size:", sys.getsizeof(text))
    compressed = zlib.compress(text, 9)
    print ("Compressed Size:", sys.getsizeof(compressed))
    ratio = sys.getsizeof(text) / sys.getsizeof(compressed)
    print ("Compression Ratio:", ratio)
```

EDIT: Hey, thanks for answering, you guys were a lot of help!

Comment: What's in this file? English text? Random bytes? No lossless compression function can compress all inputs.

Comment: Please add an example where that behaviour occurs.

Comment: If the text is small enough it may not actually save any space to compress it.

Comment: Thanks Morgan, your answer proved correct!

Comment: And user2357112, what was in my document was randomized characters, like 1000 random characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all inputs can be compressed. Your input might be too short to compress, or it might simply have no patterns or skewed statistics for the compressor to work with. Compression requires some form of redundancy in the input in order to compress.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that what I was compressing was miniscule :)